# Dual-monitor Wallpaper Lock Screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

System info: Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS
Dual 1920x1200 monitors (one HDMI, on mini-DP)

When using dual-monitors with a wallpaper set to span, Ubuntu does not correctly display the wallpaper at the login screen or at the lock screen. Is there a way to correct this behavior? I have tried this with several wallpapers at 3840x1200 resolution and display type set to "span." How can this behavior be corrected?

Login Screen: http://pasteboard.co/vZyIyqRKZ.jpg
Logged In (correctly displayed):    http://pasteboard.co/vZAtqFoTA.jpg
Lock Screen:  http://pasteboard.co/vZBNMVCi4.jpg

Comment: Desktop and login screen are handled by different things. I may have a few ideas how we might get around that, but I am currently at work and don't have access to my dual screen set up at home, so it may take some time to provide any answer

Comment: Have you had a chance to dig into this on your home setup?

Comment: Not yet. I'm currently on somewhat busy schedule.  I'll try to look into it on this weekend, probably on Friday.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug with low priority, known since 14.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1291359